# SignalR behind k8s nginx ingress disconnects immediately upon connection

Tags: kubernetes, signalr, signalr.client, azure-aks

Here's what I have for the nginx ingress:

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-set-headers:       xyz/proxy-headers
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/read-timeout:            3600
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires:  14400
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-protocols:           TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2
  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer:                      letsencrypt
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity:                cookie
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:   if ($host = 'example.com' ) {
rewrite ^ https://www.example
.com$request_uri permanent;
}

  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size:       16k
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect:      true
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size:         8m
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout:      3600
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias:            example.com
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age:  14400
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name:     affinity

...
}
```

Here's the proxy headers:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: proxy-headers
  namespace: xyz
data:
  X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
  X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
  Referrer-Policy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  Feature-Policy: "notifications 'self'; usemedia *;gyroscope: 'none'"
```

When connected directly, the websocket is fine. When it's behind nginx I get the following:

```
main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6 [2020-04-20T18:54:39.190Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6 Could not connect Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
    at _ (polyfills.d1de8a43b27b04443379.js:1)
    at t.handshakeRejecter (polyfills.d1de8a43b27b04443379.js:1)
    at t.connectionClosed (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at t.connection.onclose (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at t.stopConnection (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at t.Y.transport.onclose (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at t.close (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at t.stop (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at t.<anonymous> (main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6)
    at main.5f9ab0903b48ce06734b.js:6
```

I can't find anything that would cause it to do what it's doing and I can't get any deeper insight into what's causing it. Ideas?

Comment: Could you explain briefly about the application behind the ingress? When you said that it worked connecting "directly" you mean connecting using the service (kubectl port-forwarding)? If do you try to testing using the service directly it will help to discover if the problem is really the ingress. Will be good if you could share the service and ingress yaml.

Comment: It's a ASP.NET 3.1 WebAPI app running signalR. If you run it directly with kestrel outside of K8S entirely, the clients don't exhibit the immediate close behavior, it works first try. If you put it in k8s behind nginx, clients immediately closes and then a minute or so later connects properly. Clients are Angular using the supported SignalR npm package.

Comment: There are some logs from the nginx side? Did you tried test the application directly using kubernetes service without ingress?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I am running into similar issues with SignalR using an nginx ingress reverse proxy to kubernetes. Webserver is Kestrel on .net 6

Comment: I put in an answer for how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ultimately came up with:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-proto: https
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-forwarded-headers: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/read-timeout: "3600"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/send-timeout: "3600"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 16m
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-headers: "yournamespace/add-headers"
```

And then the following in the add-headers config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: add-headers
  namespace: yournamespace
data:
  X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
  X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
  Referrer-Policy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  Feature-Policy: "notifications 'self'; usemedia *;gyroscope: 'none'"
  kind: ConfigMap
```

This enables SignalR to work properly behind the proxy, handles affinity (which apparently was the original issue) and gives you full HSTS encryption and an A+ rating on crypto tests.